# Xamarin Forms ListView Performance

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms `ListView` in my App and this `ListView` uses different ItemTemplates selected by a `DataTemplateSelector`. With some of the Templates it works great, but also some of them are producing performance problems. Here is the code of a bad Template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
    <ViewCell>
        <Grid Padding="10,0,10,0">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
                    <Style TargetType="BoxView" BasedOn="{StaticResource InactiveStyle}"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Source="Icon.png" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

            <BoxView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsVisible="{Binding Inactive}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="Label1" Text="{Binding Column1}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>

            <BoxView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" IsVisible="{Binding Inactive}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Column2}" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>

            <BoxView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" IsVisible="{Binding Inactive}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Column3}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>

            <BoxView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" IsVisible="{Binding Inactive}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Column4}" HorizontalOptions="Start" />

            <BoxView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" IsVisible="{Binding Inactive}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Column5}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
        </Grid>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

I also have found this: [Xamarin ListView Performance](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance/) but I was not able to get it scroll faster.  It looks like it can not create the cells fast enough, so that the list scrolls jerky (Android & iOS). What can I do to get this faster?

EDIT:
I switched to `CachingStrategy="RetailElement"` and was able to optimize a few things. But always when the `OnSelectTemplate` Method is called the scrolling gets slow. Even when this Method does just return a template in the first line. So for me this looks like the Template needs to long time to be build. But I dont know why :(

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of how the `ListView` look? Will help to simplify the `DataTemplate` if thats possible. Also are you setting the `CachingStrategy`?

Comment: Well, there are 3 lines and 3 rows containing text and one image in front. the boxviews are just there to cross out the text if its inactive data

Comment: You might try using [XLabs' `ExtendedLabel`](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ExtendedLabel) which has a `IsStrikeThrough` property. This would get rid of all those `BoxView` elements. Getting rid of as many elements as possible should help.

Comment: Have you tried removing parts of the view to see what might make a difference in performance?  For instance, try removing the Image (just as a test). Knowing what parts of the layout slow things down noticeably helps determine what to do next. Also, based on your layout, it looks like you should be able to assign a constant to the Width of the first column, which will result in much faster layout time than Auto.

Comment: I removed the `BoxView` and the `Image`. But it doesn't get faster. See my edited question

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the scroll, you need to activate the appropriate RecyclingMode:

```
<ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
```

If you use a DataTemplate selector use:

```
 <ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElementAndDataTemplate" />
```

You'll probably have to adapt your DataTemplate creation process. But with this technique, OnSelectTemplate will be called only when necessary.

Moreover, if it is not enough you should perhaps split your dataTemplate in 2 depending on the Inactive state using your DataTemplateSelector logic to avoid the IsVisible Binding on your element that could be expensive.

Comment: I have already tried the CachingStaregy, but I will try to remove the inactive state now

Comment: It is maybe a bit faster, but it is still quite far away of the native speed

Comment: When you say it's slower: is it slow to load or slow to manipulate? I'm very surprised: my app has a lot of list and there's no performance issues. You can try to debug your DataTemplateSelector to be sure that it is not called to much time: OnSelectTemplate method should be called for each cell loaded.

Comment: Your ItemsSource is Bound to a List or to an ObservableCollection?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found out, that the TemplateSelector is called 1500 times on startup (50 items in collection), and two times for each item when scrolling

Comment: Ok, I was able to reduce this to 15 on startup and 1 per item when scrolling. But it is still not 100% fluently when scrolling

Comment: It's a ObservableCollection with a wrapper to load pages of data when needed

Comment: By the way, on Android `OnSelectTemplate` is 5 times more called than on iOS

Comment: That's strange... You should really create a simple demo project with a ListView using  CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" with a DataTemplateSelector and 2 template without other complexity. You will see that OnSelectTemplate is only called when required. After that add your complexity to understand why it is so much called (BindingContext change?)

Answer (score 1):

For Best option for `Xamarin.Form` Listview performance you can use native view using custom renderer.

Below are the link for Custom Renderer Example.

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/ListView

Comment: I will only use this if there is absolutely no other option. But thanks

Comment: Would I be able to use my existing XAML Templates when I decide to go for CustomRenderers?

Comment: No, You need to create native cell and render in your Listview Viewcell. And custom renderer is faster.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, move the resource dictionary from inside the template to the containing page.

Then, like others have said:

1. Make the first column fixed width
2. Replace the boxviews with your own custom label that implements strikethrough
3. Use a caching strategy

Comment: I did everything you said and it really got faster. But it is still not as fast as it should be.

Comment: The only other thing I could suggest is to try the new release of Xamarin Forms 2.4.0 and experiment with the new Android Fast Renderers.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't notice FastRenderers before. But unfortunately it does not seem to make any difference for me